# Detect stitches / seams on the leather from the image. Can it be done just with Python Open CV and built in functions for image manipulation?

Tags: python, opencv, object, detection

I am just starting with computer vision and I do not have much experience with this area. Therefore sorry for little bit generic question but I am not sure how to start and go in the correct direction.

Like in the title. I am building a system which is able to capture the image from the camera and I would like to detect if the 2 lines of stitches / seams are parallel to each other and if the gap between the lines is in specified limits / threshold. See below sample picture:

[image]

Can those lines be detected by some functions in open cv or do I need to use machine learning approach and built a model which will recognize the single stitch on the picture and then based on the detection draw new lines and perform calculations?

Comment: maybe ask on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: There’s no outta-the-box solution for this, your problem is too specific. You will need to code it by hand. Also, You need to clearly define the word “detection” for this problem. Are you looking for the position (coordinates) of the stitches? If that’s the case, you can try thresholding the image, and maybe reduce it to a column. Then locate the vertical coordinate of the white pixels. Draw horizontal lines using this information and evaluate the quality of the results.

Comment: Thanks, I will play with this over the weekend and post results as I got some similar advice on open cv forum.